# Best practice for adding a Ruby extension methods to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Array extension method I want to use in my **Rails 3** project.  **Where should it live?**

I have a app/classes where I originally put it (array_extensions.rb), and in my config/application.rb I load the path: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/app/classes)`.  However, when I drop to `rails console` the extension is not loaded.

Is there a pre-definded place I should put my extension methods for Rails 3? Or, a pre-definded way to add them?  I know Rails has it's own extensions methods for Array.  Should I add mine to `active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb`?

**What's the best practice for Rails 3?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The better way is create your extension in `lib/core_ext` directory to understand easyly where is your core_ext.

After create an initializer to require this file.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I also tried moving it to lib, but hadn't considered a separate folder for extensions. I guess my main problem was assuming that Rails would automatically load the class extension. Instead I still had to add a requires clause.

Answer (score -1):

All .rb files in `config/initializers` are required into the environment at startup; you should be putting extensions in there.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that you should put any complicated code there. That's just for configuration or requiring external files.