# Best architecture to extend two classes with the same function

Tags: ruby

I am writing a reporting gem that will have some helpers to extract data from ActiveRecord.

One function it will implement is to_report_yaml wich I need to be called from a single record (ActiveRecord::Base instance) or from an Array of records. The implementation of to_report_yaml is pretty similar in both cases so what I want is to implement it once and use duck typing to make some decisions in my logic.

My question is. What is the best way to extend ActiveRecord::Base and Array so both have a funcion called to_report_yaml pointing to the same implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement your function in a module and include it into both classes. This concept is called [Mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). It is used increasingly everywhere in Ruby libraries and is Ruby's answer to multi-inheritance (which is a broader concept, but generally harder to understand with it's edge cases).

```
module MyModule
  def to_report_yaml
    self.to_yaml # or whatever
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule
end

class Array
  include MyModule
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the class up and include a module that defines the function.

There are several tutorials, like [this one](http://www.medihack.org/2011/03/15/intend-to-extend/).

Nutshell:

```
module NewStuff
  def to_report_yaml
    # YAML it up
  end
end

class Array
  include NewStuff
end
```

There are several ways to go about doing it, including [creating a gem and using `Array.extend`](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/extending-active-record/) (and the same for `ActiveRecord`), or [creating a lib and using an initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874148/best-practice-for-adding-a-ruby-extension-methods-to-rails-3), and so on.